# Padding / Margin issue

Tags: css, tumblr

I'm working on a Tumblr theme and I've come across what I'm guessing is a CSS mistake.

The site looks *normal* when coded without the Tumblr tags. Here's what it's supposed to look like: [/octoverrain/index.html](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/613588/Tests/octoverrain/index.html)

I normally then add the Tumblr tags, paste the code into the /customize page, and see the preview on the right. It still looks *normal*. Here's a screenshot: [/octoverrain/customize-page.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/613588/Tests/octoverrain/customize-page.png)

Once I update and save the page though, all the padding/margins seem to have disappeared and I'm not sure why. Here's the URL with the *weird* mistake: http://octoverrain.net

How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: It seems like more than just the padding/margins disappear. Are you sure that your stylesheet is included?

Comment: Yeah, it's included. You'll see it's there if you view the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this: /octoverrain/index.html example you didn't write DOCTYPE (the first line in HTML source code), so the browser uses quirks mode, and that's the reason why you padding and margins work without units: `padding: 15 20 15 20`. Nowadays this practice is obsolete ;)

Try to add `px` after every number and it should work!

For the future, remember to write DOCTYPE, so you browser will use "standard mode".